# Is there a way to extract the selected value in a nested Dictionary using a for loop?

Tags: python

Using this dictionary, is there a way I can only extract the Name, Last Name, and Age of the boys?

```
myDict = {'boy1': {'Name': 'JM', 'Last Name':'Delgado', 'Middle Name':'Goneza', 'Age':'21', 
        'Birthday':'8/22/2001', 'Gender':'Male'},
        'boy2': {'Name': 'Ralph', 'Last Name':'Tubongbanua', 'Middle Name':'Castro', 
        'Age':'21', 'Birthday':'9/5/2001', 'Gender':'Male'},}

for required in myDict.values():
    print (required ['Name', 'Last Name', 'Age'])
```

The output is:

```
JM
Ralph
```

What I have in mind is

```
JM Delgado 21
Ralph Tubongbanua 21
```

Comment: Yes, was there a problem?

Comment: The problem is, I don't know how to. I keep messing up the code whenever I try to add the keys of the Last Name and Age

Comment: Why don't you copy the line for printing the name two times and replace 'Name' by 'Last Name' and 'Age'?

Comment: Please edit your question and write what is the desired output

Comment: I genuinely don't understand this question. You already extract the name of both dict entries successfully, what's stopping you from using the exact same method to get the data you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extract the keys one by one:

```
myDict = {'boy1': {'Name': 'JM', 'Last Name':'Delgado', 'Middle Name':'Goneza', 'Age':'21', 
        'Birthday':'8/22/2001', 'Gender':'Male'},
        'boy2': {'Name': 'Ralph', 'Last Name':'Tubongbanua', 'Middle Name':'Castro', 
        'Age':'21', 'Birthday':'9/5/2001', 'Gender':'Male'},}

for required in myDict.values():
    print (required['Name'], required['Last Name'],required['Age'])
```

Answer (score 1):

this could be a solution:

```py
myDict = {'boy1': {'Name': 'JM', 'Last Name':'Delgado', 'Middle, Name':'Goneza', 'Age':'21', 'Birthday':'8/22/2001', 'Gender':'Male'},
'boy2': {'Name': 'Ralph', 'Last Name':'Tubongbanua', 'Middle Name':'Castro', 
'Age':'21', 'Birthday':'9/5/2001', 'Gender':'Male'},}

for required in myDict.values():
    print(required ['Name'], required['Last Name'], required['Age'])
```

When printing multiple values separated with commas, a space will automatically appear between them.